# I can't install a game from the disk drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, dvd

I am using the administrative account on my computer. I am trying to install Skyrim on my computer. I put the disk in. I click setup.exe. I hit next. I type in my pin, etc. I hit install and it says The System Administrator has set policies to prevent this installation. I keep trying all the methods you people are all using. None of them work. I have tried the registry one. I have tried the Local Policies one. I am using Windows 7. Please help me!

Comment: This a personal or work computer?  This behavior can be explained if you were on a domain server and simply logged into an Administrator account.  The default group polices of a non-domain computer should need adjustment.  We need more information.

Comment: "I keep trying all the methods you people are all using. None of them work. I have tried the registry one. I have tried the Local Policies one" - We intuitively know exactly what you mean by that statement.

Answer (score 2):

**I need to know is your computer running on a domain?**

OR

**Do you get this error only with that application or with other external applications as well?**

**Running as an administrator:**

- Step 1:

  Run the software setup file as an administrator and check if it
  helps.

  a. Right click on the setup file of the software that you are trying
  to install.

  b. Select “Run as administrator”.

**Temporarily disabling all the antiviruses:**

- Step 2:

  Temporarily disable the antivirus software running on the computer
  and check if you are able to install the software.

**Setting the restriction Policies:**

- Step 3:

  a. Click Start, type "Local Security Policy" (without quotes) and
  press enter.

  b. Click on Software Restriction Policies.

  c. In the right pane, double click on the "enforcement".

  d. Select “All users except local administrators”.

  e. Click OK and restart the computer and check if the issue is fixed.

This is also really helpful: [Error message - The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/241/)

If you are facing further problems, please let me know :)